# How can I translate ms-access NZ to IFNULL MySQL or MariaDB functions?

Tags: mysql, regex, sed, mariadb

I am writting a "translator" of SQL queries from ms-access to MySQL or MariaDB SQL based in regex with sed.

My problem is the nz function, which has two forms:

```
     access          MariaDB or MySQL
nz(expr1,expr2) --> ifnull(expr1,expr2)
nz(expr)        --> ifnull(expr,0)
```

I have these two staments for each case, but not only one for both:

```
sed -E 's/nz\((.*),(.*)\)/ifnull\(\1,\2\)/gi'
sed -E 's/nz\((.*)\)/ifnull\(\1,0\)/gi'
```

Do you know how to merge both in only one sed stament? Or maybe using another tool as tr, awk, or perl?

**UPDATE**

For this input:

```
SELECT nz(column1),nz(column2,4),column3 FROM table;
```

The desired output is:

```
SELECT ifnull(column1,0),ifnull(column2,4),column3 FROM table;
```

Comment: Even the first statement by itself doesn't look right. What you may think of as `expr2` may contain commas, and then the first `(.*)` in your pattern will extend up to the last comma in `expr2`. You will have misidentified `expr1` and `expr2`. That can be fixed (the first subexpression should be `([^,]*)` but I am sure there are many other pitfalls. For example, `expr2` may be (or contain) another call to `nz`. Are you writing a solution that can deal with that kind of nested calls?

Comment: Unfortunatedly my poor solution can't deal with such a nested calls.
It actually consists in a sequence of sed calls joined.
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a pattern with 2 capturing groups, where the second group is optional. Then you could do a conditional replacement using perl using [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html).

**Pattern**

```
nz\(([^,()]+)(,[^,()]+)?\)
```

**Explanation**

- `nz\(` Match `nz(`
- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `[^,()]+` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 1+ times any char except `,` `(` `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture *group 2*

  - `,[^,()]+` Match `,` and match 1+ times any char except `,` `(` `)`
- `)?` Close group 2 and make it optional
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DLVFuq/1) | [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3UkGluKRIwVZBKdjVx9U5RCGvSsNQUwdEGekYAxnJ@TmluXkKbkH@vgoliUk5qdZK1lwQPXUKxfp5VTEaGtFxOhqasdqaGjowln2Mpn5KalpmXmqKhoqRpoK9glJmWl5pTo6GkoKegoqhnooRkFbSVLJCFQcJ6igYaCrpp6dacxUUZeaVgB34/z8A)

**Example code**

```
my $str = "SELECT nz(1), nz(2,3), column FROM table;";
$str =~ s/nz\(([^,()]+)(,[^,()]+)?\)/defined($2) ? "ifnull(" . $1.$2 . ")":"ifnull(" . $1 . ", 0)"/ge;
print $str
```

- `s///` is used for substitution
- `/e` is evaluation modifier
- `/g` is global modifier

**Output**

```
SELECT ifnull(1, 0), ifnull(2,3), column FROM table;
```

Comment: This little script is a good begining, but not the solution. It only substitutes the ocurrences of nz for ifnull (in separate lines), but I want the rest of text to keep unalttered. 
So for input: `SELECT nz(1), nz(2,3), column FROM table;` The output must be: `SELECT ifnull(1,0), ifnull(2,3), column FROM table;`